# how to Return an object or more than one value from a converter

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, converters, eventtocommand

hey guys as the title state, im trying to return both logitude and lattiude from my mapclicked event to my view model. here my attempt, but it didnt work.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)

{

var mapClickedEventArgs = value as Xamarin.Forms.Maps.MapClickedEventArgs;

var currentPossition = mapClickedEventArgs;

var lati = currentPossition.Position.Latitude;

var longi = currentPossition.Position.Longitude;



return lati;

}
```

Comment: this is exactly what `Position` is for.  `return currentPossition.Position;`

Comment: FYI, there's only one `s` in position

Comment: that is copied directly from the OP's code

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 good approaches:

1. You can return a value tuple:

```
public (double lati, double longi) Convert(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)

{
    var mapClickedEventArgs = value as Xamarin.Forms.Maps.MapClickedEventArgs;

    var currentPossition = mapClickedEventArgs;

    var lati = currentPossition.Position.Latitude;
    var longi = currentPossition.Position.Longitude;

    return (lati, longi);
}
```

Note, I wasn't sure what is the data type of `lati` & `longi` so I assumed it is of type `double`. In case it is a different type, please change the return values from `double` to the relevant type.

2. Return the `Position` class or create your own class that will include the properties `lati` & `longi` and instead of returning an `object`, return this class. The last row will be something like:

```
return currentPosition.Position;
```

Or:

```
return new YourClassName(lati, longi);
```

**UPDATE:**

Maybe, I didn't understand the question right. Maybe you can't change the method signature.

If this is the case, you can just return it using [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types?ranMID=46131&ranEAID=a1LgFw09t88&ranSiteID=a1LgFw09t88-H6sTUZK05Sxk9yO_uA_FOg&epi=a1LgFw09t88-H6sTUZK05Sxk9yO_uA_FOg&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2200057_aff_7806_1243925&tduid=%28ir__cl20z3o2j9kfq3zbkk0sohz31m2xrm6drpybhrws00%29%287806%29%281243925%29%28a1LgFw09t88-H6sTUZK05Sxk9yO_uA_FOg%29%28%29&irclickid=_cl20z3o2j9kfq3zbkk0sohz31m2xrm6drpybhrws00):

```
return new { lati, longi };
```